How do I use Pandoc to convert Latex to HTML such that the source code snippets inside Latex keep syntax highlighting in HTML?
I need to convert some Latex material into HTML using Pandoc. The issue I am facing is that the (C) source code snippets are not being highlighted in the HTML.
If I use the following as example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[linenos, bgcolor=yellow, autogobble, tabsize=4]{c}
        void main()
        {
            printf("I need help!\n");
        }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}

Doing the conversion using pandoc -N -f latex -t html example.tex -o example.html yields an HTML file that looks as follows:

The following link Pandoc latex to html: cannot keep code formatting suggests using minted but I see no syntax highlighting.
Any ideas?

This should work without any additional filters. The problem appears to be that the necessary highlighting styles are not part of the generated HTML. Use --standalone/-s to use the default template, or generate a custom template to include the relevant snippets.
See also this question.
